# How does MOSFET create a ground for inverter chip in this circuit

Tags: mosfet, virtual-ground

I am building an interface to a water leak sensor and after having some issues, drew the circuit diagram from an actual board to see how it works. When contacts Sens+ and Sens- are shorted together, MOSFET creates a ground for VSS and the buzzer turns on. If the contacts are open, VSS is at 7.5V and VDD is at 8.6V and CD4069 is off. I could not figure out how the MOSFET circuit works and why VSS is at 7.5V. Also, why C3 is connected to ground and not in the feedback. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the buzzer driver

[image]

here is the MOSFET circuit.

[image]

here is the MOSFET picture. You can see the silkscreen showing D, G, and S. But according to 2n7000 datasheet, the silkscreen D and S are switched around.
[image]

here is 2n7000 data sheet:
[image]

Comment: where is the power supply ground connected in the second diagram?

Comment: well, that is my puzzlement. when sens+ and sens- are connected, the Drain becomes 0V

Comment: let me re-check the board again

Comment: Is the mosfet source connected to -9V (GND)? It is missing in your diagram.

Comment: if i use the PCB silkscreen and switch around D and S, then yes. But why the data sheet shows the opposite S and D orientation for TO-92 pkg? I must be missing something.

Comment: look at the silkscreen... it's not just the lettering that is backwards ... did someone replace the mosfet?

Comment: ok, the way the MOSFET is mounted it is opposite to what the data sheet says.

Comment: my bad, the source is connected to ground (-9V). VSS still to drain. Let me review again,

Comment: My apologies. I have corrected the MOSFET circuit above. Still , i do not see how the Drain ( or VSS) is at 7.5V when SENS- is not connected to SENS+.

Comment: the MOSFET was not replaced.

Comment: So, thanks to your questions, i corrected the circuit and see how the MOSFET part works. When SENS+ and SENS- are open, the MOSFET is OPEN, VSS is at 7.7V and  CD4069 oscillator  is OFF. When SENS- and SENS+ are shorted, MOSFET Gate is at 7V and MOSFET is fully open making Drain 0V and VSS at ground, thus turning CD4069 oscillator on.   However, i still do not understand why VSS sits at 7.7V when MOSFET is open.

Answer (score 1):

Th N-FET is a low-side switch.

With open circuit between the sensor electrodes, the gate is pulled low, and the N-FET is turned off, so no current flows through the buzzer module.

If the resistance between the probe is lower than about 1M, then the gate is pulled high and the FET turns on.  Current then flows through the buzzer module.

The cap is to stop noise on the sensors turning on the gate, providing a low pass filter, with an RC time constant of about 200ms

Comment: I am using Fluke 17B meter, so the probe resistance could be up to 32M as i understand. So, if i measure between Drain and Gnd,, why do i see about 7.5V if MOSFET is open and no current is supposed to get thru? Unless, i misread the meter impedance and it is less than that of a drain and the meter creates a ground path?

Comment: When the FET is off, it is effectively very high resistance, so most of the 9v supply should be dropped over the FET, with almost no current through the buzzer.

Comment: Ah, i think i got it. This is as if i have a voltage divider with some low R1 (4069) in series with FET as R2 going to gnd. Then FET resistance is so high, all the voltage ends being on FET. Thank you very much.